# Do the Dothraki practice extramarital sex?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Obviously, raping and pillaging is a large part of Dothraki culture, however they do take wives. So I'm wondering, once a Dothraki man is wed, will he still take part in rape and sex with other women?

In the show, I remember Drogo once mentioning that he will rape the women of Westeros, but I'm not sure if he mentions that in the book.  Other than that moment, it seems that Drogo is devoted to Dany.

To be clear, I am looking for evidence from the books, not the HBO series.

Comment: im pretty sure he still has sex with whoever he wants in the book, but ill have to read farther, it was at least implied that they have multipul partners.

Comment: It is mentioned that some Khals (but not Drogo) would share their wives with their blood riders, so I'd say that extramarital sex is not exactly frowned upon.

Comment: Counterquestion: Do Dothraki practice marriage? We have only seen that their Khals may marry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you were looking for this. Drogo says this after failed attempt to poison Dany. So this is after their marriage.

> “And to Rhaego son of Drogo, the stallion who will mount the world, to him I also pledge a gift. To him I will give this iron chair his mother’s father sat in. I will give him Seven Kingdoms. I, Drogo, khal, will do this thing.” His voice rose, and he lifted his fist to the sky. “I will take my khalasar west to where the world ends, and ride the wooden horses across the black salt water as no khal has done before. I will kill the men in the iron suits and tear down their stone houses. I will rape their women, take their children as slaves, and bring their broken gods back to Vaes Dothrak to bow down beneath the Mother of Mountains. This I vow, I, Drogo son of Bharbo. This I swear before the Mother of Mountains, as the stars look down in witness.”
>
> <sub><sup>A Game Of Thrones</sup></sub>

A khal could share his wives with his bloodriders.

> Every khal had his bloodriders. At first Dany had thought of them as a kind of Dothraki Kingsguard, sworn to protect their lord, but it went further than that. Jhiqui had taught her that a bloodrider was more than a guard; they were the khal’s brothers, his shadows, his fiercest friends. “Blood of my blood,” Drogo called them, and so it was; they shared a single life. The ancient traditions of the horselords demanded that when the khal died, his bloodriders died with him, to ride at his side in the night lands. If the khal died at the hands of some enemy, they lived only long enough to avenge him, and then followed him joyfully into the grave. In some khalasars, Jhiqui said, the bloodriders shared the khal’s wine, his tent, and even his wives, though never his horses. A man’s mount was his own.
>
> <sub><sup>A Game Of Thrones</sup></sub>

After conquering a city, Dothraki men would pillage the city and rape all the women they can get their hands on. The survivors would be sold into slavery.

> Behind them, the girl being raped made a heartrending sound, a long sobbing wail that went on and on and on. Dany’s hand clenched hard around the reins, and she turned the silver’s head. “Make them stop,” she commanded Ser Jorah.
>
> “Khaleesi?” The knight sounded perplexed.
>
> “You heard my words,” she said. “Stop them.” She spoke to her khas in the harsh accents of Dothraki. “Jhogo, Quaro, you will aid Ser Jorah. I want no rape.”
>
> Jorah Mormont spurred his horse closer. “Princess,” he said, “you have a gentle heart, but you do not understand. This is how it has always been. Those men have shed blood for the khal. Now they claim their reward.”
>
> <sub><sup>A Game Of Thrones</sup></sub>

Even Dothraki weddings involved rape and killing.

> The warriors were watching too. One of them finally stepped into the circle, grabbed a dancer by the arm, pushed her down to the ground, and mounted her right there, as a stallion mounts a mare. Illyrio had told her that might happen. **“The Dothraki mate like the animals in their herds. There is no privacy in a khalasar, and they do not understand sin or shame as we do.”**
>
> Dany looked away from the coupling, frightened when she realized what was happening, but a second warrior stepped forward, and a third, and soon there was no way to avert her eyes. Then two men seized the same woman. She heard a shout, saw a shove, and in the blink of an eye the arakhs were out, long razor-sharp blades, half sword and half scythe. A dance of death began as the warriors circled and slashed, leaping toward each other, whirling the blades around their heads, shrieking insults at each clash. No one made a move to interfere.
>
> It ended as quickly as it began. The arakhs shivered together faster than Dany could follow, one man missed a step, the other swung his blade in a flat arc. Steel bit into flesh just above the Dothraki’s waist, and opened him from backbone to belly button, spilling his entrails into the dust. As the loser died, the winner took hold of the nearest woman—not even the one they had been quarreling over—and had her there and then. Slaves carried off the body, and the dancing resumed.
>
> Magister Illyrio had warned Dany about this too. “A Dothraki wedding without at least three deaths is deemed a dull affair,” he had said. Her wedding must have been especially blessed; before the day was over, a dozen men had died.
>
> <sub><sup>A Game Of Thrones</sup></sub>

**So the simple answer is yes.**